# Inject UnitTest classes

Tags: java, android-studio, junit, dagger-2

Hello I have the following problem using Dagger 2 in my (part) project being completely pure-Java with no android dependencies.

When I run the unit tests using some mocks (e.g. Injecting a Mock Network Connector returning static Strings) over the Gradle view or console (businessModule:test) there are no problems and all tests Succeed. But when I open the files in Android Studio the Studio says that the Return of my DaggerMockComponent is not compatible with the target type. Opening the generated Component-Implementation, I see that Android Studio thinks the TestUnit-Class (and the interface MockComponent) is not available so it does not know what the inject method returns.

I have the following gradle file:

apply plugin: 'java'

```
// allow inject of core into core. https://github.com/griffio/dagger2-example
sourceSets {
    dagger {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/dagger/java']
        }
    }
    daggerTest {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/daggerTest/java']
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    compileDagger
}

compileJava {
    description = "dagger annotation processor is loaded automatically from classpath"
    sourceSets.dagger.java.srcDirs*.mkdirs()
    classpath += configurations.compileDagger
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-s', sourceSets.dagger.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
    ]
}

compileTestJava {
    //dependsOn compileDaggerTestJava
    description = "dagger annotation processor is loaded automatically from classpath"
    sourceSets.daggerTest.java.srcDirs*.mkdirs()
    classpath += configurations.compileDagger
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-s', sourceSets.daggerTest.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
            //'-s src/testDaggerJava'
    ]
}

task deleteDagger(type: Delete) {
    delete 'src/dagger', 'src/daggerTest'
}

clean.dependsOn deleteDagger

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Force Java 7 as newer versions can not be processed by dex for API 21
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

    [...]

    // Dagger for dependency injection
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    compileOnly 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    testCompileOnly 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'

    [...]

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everybody, after an additional night and some research on the android-apt plugin I stumbled over the pure-Java apt ([net.ltgt.apt](http:///https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.ltgt.apt)) and now I have a working solution in combination with the idea-plugin

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: "idea"

task cleanGenerated(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build'
}

clean.dependsOn cleanGenerated


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Force Java 7 as newer versions can not be processed by dex for API 21
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

    [...]

    // Dagger for dependency injection
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    testApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'

    [...]

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Of course you have to add the dependency and plugin-name in the root gradle file but that is written down in the [documentation for net.ltgt.apt](http:///https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.ltgt.apt) - hope this works for you, too.